# Android Cursor not returning anything when using a UUID in my where clause

Tags: android, sql

I'm trying to select some rows from my sqlLight table in Android. Here is my code for my cursor.

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PRODUCT_TYPES, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CODE, KEY_GROUPID }, KEY_GROUPID + "=?", new String[] { group }, null, null, null);
```

I have also tried to do it this way:

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PRODUCT_TYPES, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CODE, KEY_GROUPID }, KEY_GROUPID + "='" + group + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

The problem I am having is that the cursor is empty every time I run these queries.

If I run it without the where clause it works just fine and it returns all of the rows in the table. I can also run the query with the where clause on another column with no problem, for example:

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PRODUCT_TYPES, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CODE, KEY_GROUPID }, KEY_CODE + "=?", new String[] { "TPEO128" }, null, null, null);
```

Let me know if there is any other information that you would like for me to post.

Comment: Log the group that you passed in and see what the value is.

Comment: Hoan I checked the string and it was fine. Do you think that it would be a problem if the column in the table is a uniqueidentifier and the group param I'm passing in is a string?

Comment: You mean KEY_GROUPID is an INTEGER?

Comment: Why don't you hard code a group using the first query. If it is OK then it has to do with the pass in group. I don't know how you obtain group so It is hard to say. Post the code that obtain group.

Comment: Hoan the KEY_GROUPID is a String and the GroupId column in the database is a uniqueidentifier. Also, to answer your second question, I have hard coded it into my query before and no luck. I assure you the value of group, before used in the query, is a valid 36 character Guid. I will post more code as soon as I get home tonight. Thank you.

Comment: Put a comment here when you posted more code.

Answer (score 0):

You correct open database for read or write? Exception don't exists?

If no exception, you may try write your group string before execute query.

```
Log.d("String from where", group);
```

Maybe this string isn't in column `KEY_GROUPID`?

Comment: I am opening my database before I execute my query. There are no exceptions. I did a log on the group string and it is correct before the query. And I triple checked that the KEY_GROUPID string is the same the the column name. Can you think of anything else?

Comment: Try seen what is in the Cursor, c.count(), if is 0 your query execute on database. In this case, maybe you have some char in string witch is not 0-9 or A-Z. Maybe you have troble with database encoding.

Comment: Juraj, I will give that a shot when I get home tonight and keep you posted. Thank you for the replies.